# what's the alternative of appSettings in mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What's the alternative of ”appSettings of web.config” in mvc 6.  Do i need to create a custom json file and read it in the application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative is [Configuration](https://github.com/aspnet/configuration).

It supports JSON, XML, ini, environment variables and command line arguments.

Comment: I am agree with you but it means that we no longer have to use ConfigurationManager. If we have to support static helper like configuration manager then we have to create our own utility. Right ?